# how to filer a set of records that must satisfy all conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a set of objects that have some filterable information on them based upon a selected object.

I have the following and would like to iterate over the keys in `selected` and only return items that satisfy ALL the conditions (in this case user `Amber` who has `tagId` of 12 AND `placementId` of 27).

One caveat is that if a `selected` filter is equal to null, it should be excluded from the filtering as this means that a user isn't filtering by that.

This will grow to like 8 filters so don't want to do some big if statement. How could I do this?

```
var selected = {};
selected["tagId"] = 12;
selected["placementId"] = 27;
selected["locationId"] = null;

var users = [];
users.push({"name":"Joe", "tagIds":[3,4,12], "placementIds": [2,19]});
users.push({"name":"Suzy", "tagIds":[3,4], "placementIds": [2,19, 27]});
users.push({"name":"Amber", "tagIds":[1,12], "placementIds": [2,19, 27]});

function filterBySelected(items){
    var hits = [];
    console.log('within filter by Selected');
    console.log(items);
    for (var key in selected){
        if(selected[key]){ // 
            console.log('you are filtering by: ' + key);
        }
    }
    return hits;
}
var items = filterBySelected(users);
// items should return user object of "Amber"
```

Comment: Do you always just search through an array? Or could there be an item like `"teamId": 20` which you would be filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter` and `Object.entries` (or a polyfill for it) as follows:

```js
var selected = {tagId: 12,placementId: 27};

var users = [
    {"name":"Joe", "tagIds":[3,4,12], "placementIds": [2,19]},
    {"name":"Suzy", "tagIds":[3,4], "placementIds": [2,19, 27]},
    {"name":"Amber", "tagIds":[1,12], "placementIds": [2,19, 27]}
];

function filterBySelected(items){
    return items.filter(item => 
        Object.entries(selected).every(([k, v]) => 
            v == null || (item[k+"s"] || []).includes(v)
        )
    );
}

var items = filterBySelected(users);

console.log(items);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: cool - this looks good (and a bit beyond me)!  Do I need to polyfill this for browsers? Also, what if I wanted to ONLY filter by items that were not null (sorry,should have included this in original question). Say we also have a `locationId:null` in the selected object and wouldn't want to form them to have locationIds equal to null?

Comment: Depends on which browser support you need? Support is getting wide spread. See bottom of [mdn page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) - as often, IE is the exception. I added the extra condition on `null` (which will also work the same for when the selected value is `undefined`).

Comment: this looks awesome. thx - on the road now but really appreciate it. Have a great weekend!